# AudioContext / MediaRecorder working on mobile browser but not in cordova

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, mediarecorder, audiocontext

I'm working on a ["launchpad" type app.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTx3G6h2xyA) I've got the app working on desktop and mobile browser, but for some reason I can't get it to work in cordova.

I've boiled the app down to it's simplest form in the code below. You can also find a [working version, here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/test-audio-context/index.html), and [a demo cordova project, here](https://github.com/adam-hanna/cordova-audio-context).

Some more details:

- No errors get thrown
- I've only tested on Android
- I've also tried with crosswalk
- You can see that the base64 encoded audio that it generates is just blank in cordova but is a big long string, otherwise.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">-->
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h3>First, choose a file</h3>
            <input id="input" type="file" accept="audio/*" onchange="inputChanged()"/>
            <h3>Second, play the file</h3>
            <audio id="audio" loop controls></audio>
            <h3>Third, hit the record button. Click again to stop recording.</h3>
            <button id="record" data-state="stopped">Record</button>
            <h3>Finally, listen to your recording!</h3>
            <audio id="player" controls></audio>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /*
             * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
             * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
             * distributed with this work for additional information
             * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
             * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
             * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
             * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
             *
             * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
             *
             * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
             * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
             * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
             * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
             * specific language governing permissions and limitations
             * under the License.
             */

            // elems
            var input = document.getElementById("input")
            var audio = document.getElementById("audio")
            var record = document.getElementById("record")
            var player = document.getElementById("player")

            // html5 audio
            var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)()
            var recorderDest = context.createMediaStreamDestination()
            var chunks = []
            var mediaRecorder = new window.MediaRecorder(recorderDest.stream)
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
                // push each chunk (blobs) in an array
                chunks.push(e.data)
            }
            mediaRecorder.onstop = function (e) {
                // Make blob out of our blobs, and open it.
                var blob = new window.Blob(
                    chunks,
                    {
                        "type": "audio/ogg; codecs=opus"
                    }
                )

                var reader = new window.FileReader()
                reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
                reader.onloadend = function() {
                    player.src = reader.result
                }
                // player.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                window.theBlob = blob
                chunks = []
            }
            var app = {
                // Application Constructor
                initialize: function() {
                    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

                    // events
                    record.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                        console.log("click", record.dataset.state)
                        if (record.dataset.state === "stopped") {
                            // first, create a blank buffer
                            // we need to do this because we need to "record" negative space
                            // or times when a pad isn't playing
                            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createBuffer
                            var blankBuffer = context.createBuffer(2, 22050, 44100)
                            var blankSource = context.createBufferSource()
                            blankSource.buffer = blankBuffer
                            blankSource.connect(recorderDest)
                            blankSource.loop = true
                            blankSource.start(0)

                            mediaRecorder.start()
                            record.dataset.state = "recording"
                            record.innerHTML = "recording"
                            record.style.backgroundColor = "red"
                        } else {
                            mediaRecorder.stop()
                            record.dataset.state = "stopped"
                            record.innerHTML = "record"
                            record.style.backgroundColor = "white"
                        }
                    })
                },

                // deviceready Event Handler
                //
                // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
                // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
                onDeviceReady: function() {
                    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
                },

                // Update DOM on a Received Event
                receivedEvent: function(id) {
                    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
                    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
                    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

                    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
                    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

                    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
                }
            };

            app.initialize();

            function inputChanged () {
                console.log("changed")
                var file = input.files[0]
                var fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
                
                audio.src = fileUrl

                var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio)
                source.connect(context.destination)
                source.connect(recorderDest)
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm totally stumped and am getting frustrated. Thanks for any help!

Comment: [Holy ish... does this mean that media recorder defaults to the mic and won't take any other source? WTH!?](https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-4971)